# How do I back up a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql

I have created a Web Application using Java JSP and for a Database I used MySql server 5.5. I am running on windows and the application works just fine. My question is, where is the actual physical database stored, i can not find it anywhere on my computer, and the reason why i am asking is portability, if i copy and paste and run the project on different machine, there is a problem connecting to the database, i can recreate the schema of the database, but the actual data stored in the database i can not find it.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to backup your database:

> The mysqldump client is a backup program originally written by Igor
>   Romanenko. It can be used to dump a database or a collection of
>   databases for backup or transfer to another SQL server (not
>   necessarily a MySQL server). The dump typically contains SQL
>   statements to create the table, populate it, or both. However,
>   mysqldump can also be used to generate files in CSV, other delimited
>   text, or XML format.

An alternative option if you don't want to use the commandline is to use a program like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)